# Center image returned by instafeed.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, instafeedjs

Im using [Instafeed.js](http://instafeedjs.com/) 
to make an instagram livefeed. Everything is fine, but I want to center the image returned by instafeed. I have tried to use a lot of different ways, but it does not seem to behave as expected.

My HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Scenekvelder</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/instafeed.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var feed = new Instafeed({
get: "tagged",
tagName: "de3musketereroslo",
clientId: "d07f4ce08c6d4251b9fbb813d1fae305",
resolution: "standard_resolution",
limit: 1,
sortBy: "most-recent"
});

feed.run();

setInterval(function () {location.reload()}, 10000);


</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Livefeed fra instagram #De3MusketererOslo</h1>
<main>
<div id="wrapper" class="center">
<div id="insta-wrap">
<div id="instafeed"></div>
</div>
</div>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```html
body {
background: #000000;
}

h1 {
color: #FFFFFF;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 2cm;
}

.center {
align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to center horizontally, vertically, or both?

Answer (score 0):

According to  [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_align-items.asp), "align-items" only works in flexible elements, and I assume that what css you've posted it all actual css. Therefore, do this

```
.center {
    display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
    -webkit-align-items: center; /* Safari 7.0+ */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Depending on how the rest of your layout works, and if the instagram feed simply gives you img-tags, you might just want to do:

```
.center img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```